# Creating a homepage with Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, git

I've been at this for a while now and I can't seem to get this right.

I have recently created a simple game that you can access at the github pages like https://myusername.github.io/nameofgame.

I would like to, in addition to this, create a homepage, which can be accessed at https://myusername.github.io

My current process is the following:

```
create-react-app myusername.github.io <br>
cd into it
npm run build
add "homepage": "https://coloringnuns.github.io" into package.json
npm run build
npm install --save-dev gh-pages
add "deploy" : "npm run build && gh-pages -d build" into scripts in package.json
git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/myusername.github.io.git
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push -u origin master
npm run deploy
```

However, while this does publish myusername.github.io, it actually only shows the readme.md file instead of the actual app. I followed the protocols at https://medium.freecodecamp.org/surge-vs-github-pages-deploying-a-create-react-app-project-c0ecbf317089; why doesn't it work?

Comment: Here are the official instructions: https://pages.github.com/. By default, I believe it serves the contents of the master branch of the repository (which might be your source files). Make sure it's configured to serve the built web directory (or branch) of your project.

Comment: The process outlined there doesn't apply very well to create-react-app. However, nothing I'm doing deviates that much from that process, so I still don't see what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: Did you enable github pages on the repo?

Comment: Yes. They are enabled by default.

Comment: Just a guess, but you might be having problems because the default config might not work for a user-level GitHub Pages (instead of a project). The docs for the NPM package you're using are here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages. What is the output when you run it in debug mode? `NODE_DEBUG=gh-pages npm run deploy`